# How to define useState nested array types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, use-state

How I define types for nested array in UseState array

defined interface -

```
interface ToyProps {
  car: string | null;
  doll: number | null;
}

interface SettingsProps {
  [key: string]: ToyProps[];
}
```

state -

```
const [state, setstate]:SettingsProps = React.useState({
  toys: [
    {
      cars: "car 1",
      doll: "doll 1",
    },
    {
        cars: "car 2",
        doll: "doll 3",
    },
  ],
});
```

I defined in the above way but I still get a type error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're applying the type to the array, which contains both the state object and the state setter function.

Instead, supply it as a type argument to `useState`:

```typescript
const [state, setstate] = React.useState<SettingsProps>({
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // ...
});
```

The type argument drives the return type of `useState`, which will set the types of `state` and `setstate` appropriately.